pydevd - how to intercept mode switch - running, paused
I'm building a Python debugging extension and I'd like it to work with Pydevd. It'd be useful to be able to add a callback which is called just before the main program is paused and control handed to the debugger, and called just before resume when the program is resumed. Is there a callback interface to allow this, or what approach is suggested?
Looking for advice on approach

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
